# HTML: variable not defined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button, datatables

Why is one of the variables not defined?

**GET DLETE ID undefined**

- where is that in `console.log("GET DLETE ID", id)`? The id is not defined
- but in line 70 `console.log("GET edit DATA", data)`. Until here, it can still get and print the data and id

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Meta tags and other head elements -->
  <title>Account Management</title>

<body>

  <h1>Account Management</h1>
    <main id="main-holder">


    </main>
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>

  <script>

var Selected_add_edit_api;

    $(document).ready(function () {
      const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token")

      console.log("GET TOKEN", getToken)

      var table = $("#example").DataTable({
        ajax: {
          url: "http://192.168.10.01:8000/api/user_info/",
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken
          },
          dataSrc: function (response) {
            console.log("DATA", response.users);
            return response.users
          }
        },
        columns: [
          {
            data: null,
            title: "ACTION",
            render: function (data, type, row) {
              return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="Edit_Data" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever=" ">Edit</button>' +
                '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete-btn" id="Delete_Data" data-id="' + row.device_id + '">Delete</button>';
            }
          },


          { data: "userid", title: "Login ID" },
          { data: "name", title: "Name" },
          { data: "acc_type", title: "Account Type" },
          { data: "created_at", title: "Created Time" }
        ]
      });


      table.draw()


      var rowData;

      $('#example tbody').on('click', 'button', function (event) {


        var data = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
        rowData = data;

        console.log("GET edit DATA", data)              // here still can get and pint the data and id

      });


      $(function() {
      $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var recipient = button.data('whatever');
        var modal = $(this);
        var data = rowData;

        var inputFields = modal.find('.modal-body input');

        if (button.attr('id') == "AddedNew_Data02" || button.attr('id') == "AddedNew_Data" ) {
          inputFields.val("");
          modal.find('.modal-title').text('Add Data ' + recipient);
          Selected_add_edit_api = "add-api";
        } else {
          var keys = Object.keys(data);
          for (var i = 0; i < inputFields.length; i++) {
            var inputValue = data[keys[i]];
            var inputValue = rowData[keys[i]];
            modal.find('.modal-title').text('Edit Data ' + recipient);
            Selected_add_edit_api = "edit-api";
            $(inputFields[i]).val(inputValue);
          }
        }
      });
    });




      function editRow_website(id){



        var device_id=document.getElementById("userid"+id);
        var name=document.getElementById("name"+id);
        var acc_type=document.getElementById("acc_type"+id);


        let getEditData = {
          "userid": userid,
          "name": name,
          "account type": acc_type,

        }

        document.getElementById("#editid input").value = device_id

      }


      $(document).on('click', '.delete-btn', function (event) {
        var id = $(this).data('id')

        console.log("GET DLETE ID", id)

        confirmDelete(id)
      });

      function deleteData(id) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://192.168.10.01:8000/api/user_info/?id="+ id,
          type:'DELETE',
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken
          },
          success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
          }

        }).then(res => console.log("RES", res));
      }
    });
  </script>
```

---

If I add `console.log("row", row);` to show row, all the row of the data will show up.

[image]

```
        columns: [
          {
            data: null,
            title: "ACTION",
            render: function (data, type, row) {
              console.log("row", row);
              return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="Edit_Data" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever=" ">Edit</button>' +
                '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete-btn" id="Delete_Data" data-id="' + row.device_id + '">Delete</button>';
            }
          },


          { data: "userid", title: "Login ID" },
          { data: "name", title: "Name" },
          { data: "acc_type", title: "Account Type" },
          { data: "created_at", title: "Created Time" }
        ]
      });
```

Comment: The problem must be that `row.device_id` is undefined when rendering. What does `console.log(row)` show in the `render:` function?

Comment: I edit the result on my post, pls take a look

Comment: @happybeginer In the latest picture, i can see that you have `device_id`. Maybe it should be `row.id`

Comment: You have `row.device_id` in the code but the screenshot shows `userid` that is highlighted. If you have similar error add console.log with your variable that is not defined like `console.log(row.device_id)` to see what exactly you're saving.

Comment: It is close to incomprehensible. Are you using [machine translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Translate)?

Comment: Why `DLETE` and not `DELETE`?

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76561548/edit). Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi @Peter Mortensen,  `DLETE` just the naming for console log for me to understand, did my post incomprehensible? I would improve my speaking later on

Answer (score 1):

need to change into `row.userid`, so that the extracted data knows who you calling with

```
        columns: [
          {
            data: null,
            title: "ACTION",
            render: function (data, type, row) {
              return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="Edit_Data" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever=" ">Edit</button>' +
                '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete-btn" id="Delete_Data" data-id="' + row.userid + '">Delete</button>';
            }
          },
```

now, it works fine